# NextJS Static Export Specify .env

Tags: variables, next.js, static, export, environment

I have a NextJS app with a Django backend. The NextJS app is statically exported which the Django app redirects too.

When exporting, NextJS uses `.env.production` by default, however when developing locally I'd prefer it to use `.env.development` however I can't figure out how to specify that.

When running via `npm run dev` it uses the proper `.env` however there is limited info on if this is even possible to choose for the static export - I've just been switching the contents of the files as needed.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the command `next dev` (`npm run dev`) is run, Next.js [sets the `NODE_ENV` environment variable](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/bin/next.ts#L88-L106) to `development` (`production` for anything else, e.g., `export`) and will load the following files in top-to-bottom order:

1. `.env.development.local`
2. `.env.local`
3. `.env.development`
4. `.env`

So there's no need to specify that `.env.development` should be used — it just needs to exist in your project's root directory.

`.env.local` gets loaded in both `development` and `production` environments, but not in `test`.

`.env` gets loaded in all three environments.

Variables in `.env*.local` will override the same variables in `.env`, `.env.development`, and `.env.production`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mark! I may have explained poorly so let me try again

I only use `"next build && next export"` for this project and am able to access variables good and well. 

I have `.env.development` and `.env.production` in my root directory and it seems no matter what the export uses `.env.production` since in some docs it seems to have higher priority

I'm thinking now based on your answer though my solution is to add a `.env.local` since that will take higher precedence?

Comment: @DanielN. Correct, `.env.local` takes a higher precedence as it will always override default variables set in the others.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `next dev` script, next.js will load the environment variables from `.env.development`

If you run `next start` script next.js will load the envrionment variables from `.env.production`

Next.js does not use `.env.production` by default it uses `.env.local` by default. `.env.local` will override anything on the .development or .production files.